# How to Upload Image with Additional Data in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I upload an image with other additional data together **(Name, Email, Image, DOB, etc.)** at a time on Firebase Realtime Database in Android App?

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: No, I don't want to download the image and set url. I want it will take right from the image gallery, and upload

Answer (score 0):

step 1: get the download url from the uploaded image

val ref = storageRef.child("images/mountains.jpg")

```
uploadTask = ref.putFile(file)

val urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask { task ->
    if (!task.isSuccessful) {
        task.exception?.let {
            throw it
        }
    }
    ref.downloadUrl
}.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        val downloadUri = task.result
    } else {
        // Handle failures
        // ...
    }
}
```

step 2:
crate a data class which contain all ur data like name, email, picture_location etc...

step 3:
in picture location variable store the download url

step 4: and save in realtime or firestore db

***u cant save data directly inside image***

step 5: using picasso or glide library u can redownload the image and show it in your app u just need that download url